# jbpm 6 installer Parse Unexpected element '{urn:jboss:weld:1.0}weld

Tags: java, jboss, jbpm, jboss-eap-6

I've been trying to install and  configure jbpm 6 with jboss EAP 6.3. this are the steps i've followed

- Download installer  6.1.0.Final
- Modify build properties so that it downloads and installs Jboss EAP 6.3
- Run ant with task install.demo.noeclipse
- Run jboss standalone with command standalone.bat -c standalone-full.xml

but when jboss is starting i get the following error:

```
13:17:12,726 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-13) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."jbpm-console.war".STRUCTURE: org.jboss.msc.service.S
tartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."jbpm-console.war".STRUCTURE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment "jbpm-console.war"
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:166) [jboss-as-server-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1980) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1913) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS018774: Error loading jboss-all.xml from D:\aplicaciones\jbpm-installer\jboss-eap-6.3\standalone\tmp\vf
s\temp\temp6550191ba3e3899f\jbpm-console.war-3ff84d61f611b8c7\META-INF\jboss-all.xml
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.jbossallxml.JBossAllXMLParsingProcessor.parse(JBossAllXMLParsingProcessor.java:153) [jboss-as-server-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.jbossallxml.JBossAllXMLParsingProcessor.parse(JBossAllXMLParsingProcessor.java:128) [jboss-as-server-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.jbossallxml.JBossAllXMLParsingProcessor.deploy(JBossAllXMLParsingProcessor.java:96) [jboss-as-server-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159) [jboss-as-server-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
        ... 5 more
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[18,3]
Message: Unexpected element '{urn:jboss:weld:1.0}weld'
        at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:108) [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.0.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLExtendedStreamReaderImpl.handleAny(XMLExtendedStreamReaderImpl.java:69) [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.0.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.jbossallxml.JBossAllXMLParsingProcessor$Parser.parseJBossElement(JBossAllXMLParsingProcessor.java:203) [jboss-as-server-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.jbossallxml.JBossAllXMLParsingProcessor$Parser.readElement(JBossAllXMLParsingProcessor.java:192) [jboss-as-server-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.jbossallxml.JBossAllXMLParsingProcessor$Parser.readElement(JBossAllXMLParsingProcessor.java:176) [jboss-as-server-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
        at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:110) [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.0.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.parseDocument(XMLMapperImpl.java:69) [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.0.Final-redhat-2]
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.jbossallxml.JBossAllXMLParsingProcessor.parse(JBossAllXMLParsingProcessor.java:148) [jboss-as-server-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
        ... 8 more
```

I'm very confused since the installer is set to work (aparently) with jboss eap 6.1.1 and the migration to 6.3 should be straigh forward.

Has anyone solved this?